# Best way to do a timetable in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to decide on the best way to display a timetable to the user.

Ideally I wanted the data to be displayed in a table layout but I quickly realized that each table row required like 18 text views for the relevant data.

I've checked a calendar component, no use. A table layout does seem the best way to go but what's the best way to implement it so that it's easy to get data from my DB and read it into the table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use GridView with its adapter:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html